# Color text in input ( by position )

Tags: jquery, input

I need to create an input type having text, of different color .

Ex. first 5 characters in color black and the rest in red

Is this possible with jquery or something ?

By input i mean

```
<input type="text" value="blackreddddd" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any code , that you have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean by "width based color" ?

Comment: @JotDhaliwal he tried Nothing , so he is asking

Comment: I don't even know if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which can accept no of characters and then replace the html with the same.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ts81tyj9/)

Code for the same:

```
var str = $('#test').html();

function color(noOfCharacters) {
    $('#test').html('<span style="color:red">' + str.substr(0, noOfCharacters) + '</span><span>' + str.substr(noOfCharacters, str.length) + '</span>');
}
color(4);
```

Comment: I need this for a text input in a form not a span